# I used the slice method in this JS code and my code is slow, is there a way to make this code faster?

Tags: javascript, optimization

Here is a kata from Codewars:

'If you have completed the Tribonacci sequence kata, you would know by now that mister Fibonacci has at least a bigger brother. If not, give it a quick look to get how things work.

Well, time to expand the family a little more: think of a Quadribonacci starting with a signature of 4 elements and each following element is the sum of the 4 previous, a Pentabonacci (well Cinquebonacci would probably sound a bit more Italian, but it would also sound really awful) with a signature of 5 elements and each following element is the sum of the 5 previous, and so on.

Well, guess what? You have to build an Xbonacci function that takes a signature of X elements - and remember each next element is the sum of the last X elements - and returns the first n elements of the so seeded sequence.'

and this is my solution:

```
function Xbonacci(signature,n){
 let i=0;
  let k = n - signature.length;
   while(k--){
     let sumNums = 0;
     signature.slice(i , signature.length ).map((num)=>{
      return sumNums += num;
     })
     
     signature.push(sumNums);
     i++
   }
  return signature;
}
```

but it's not passing the test because of optimization problems. I don't know how to optimize this code. is there any solution to make this code faster?

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for code that doesn't work. If you want to improve your functioning code, please post this in [codereview.se] after reading their [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) and [faq](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes) pages.

Comment: @adiga: this is questionable at best. The code that is so slow that it doesn't pass the timer test, does NOT work and hence on-topic here.

Comment: @Amir: think of it this way: assume you have a sum of last N elements, what would be the next sum? Can you use simple arithmetics to get nextSum from sum?